Hangman School Project Code Debugging C++
I'm trying to program a simple hangman game. I'm trying to have the program run until someone guesses the word but only give them 6 strikes. So basically the counter only increments when the person guesses a letter that is not in the string. I also want it to display "Try again" when the person gets it wrong.
For some reason it does't work the way I want it to. It prints "try again" multiple times, not just once, and I can't get the counter situation right.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string hidden;
    string answer;
    char guess;
    int counter = 0;
    cout << "Give me a word (5-15 chars): ";
    cin >> hidden;

    int length = hidden.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        answer.insert(i,"*");

    do {
        cout << "The Word is: " << answer << endl;
        cout << "What is your guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length(); i++) {
            if (guess == hidden[i]) {
                answer[i] = guess;
                cout << "Correct Guess!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Try again!";
                counter++;
            }
        }
        
        if (answer == hidden) {
            cout << "You have guessed the word!";
            break;
        }
    } while (counter < 7);
    
    cout << "Game over: >>" << answer << "<<";
}


You have to carefully check if the code that you wrote does what you want it to, because your description of its behavior is correct. It is written to do what you describe not what you want.

FYI -- Instead of the first for loop setting up answer, you don't need a for loop.
This answer.resize(hidden.length(), '*'); does the same thing.

It prints 'try again' multiple times because you put it inside your loop. Instead you should put it after the loop and only print it if the guess is equal to nothing in the hidden string.

Here's how to do this
    bool any_right = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length(); i++) {
        if (guess == hidden[i]) {
            answer[i] = guess;
            any_right = true;
        }
    }
    if (any_right) {
        cout << "Correct Guess!" << endl;
    }
    else {
       cout << "Try again!";
       counter++;
    }

Beginners often struggle with what I call existential conditions. In this case you have to print 'correct' if any of the letters match, you have to print 'try again' and increment the counter if none of the latters match. You cannot make these decisions inside the loop, only after the loop when you have examined all the letters.
See how in the code above I introduced a bool variable any_right, this starts off false but is set to true if any of the letters match. Only after the loop has finished do I examine that variable and print the appropriate message and maybe increment the counter.

Thank you so much! This solved my problem perfectly and I understand why it needs to be done the way you did it! I appreciate your help!

Also consider std::any_of and std::none_of, which can help make this clearer
